# SQL Server 2008 - can't connect in window

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2008 on Windows 8. When I was installing, I got a message alert

[image]

Everything is completed but when I test connection, it cannot access with a message:

[image]

I have uninstalled and re-installed again but it's still the same result for me. I tried to solve the issue with [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

but I can't find button `Add port` or `SQL` in exceptions in My Computer as [image].

Question:

I think SQL Server 2008 is not supported on Windows 8? Because the same software I have installed worked well on my Windows 7.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks

I am looking for your reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to install SQL Server 2008 in Windows 8 but by reading this [MSDN KB page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562) it looks like that it should be supported but not right out of the box. You will have to do some juggling before you will be able use it. That KB page should give you better idea.

Plus in order to add that PORT, you have to goto Windows Firewall and add PORT into list. This [MSFT help page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-firewall-from-start-to-finish) should give you idea about how to do that.